# GWT: How to Use Place Tokens

Tags: java, gwt

As a little example: Take a website where you land on a login page and after a successful login getting directed to the main page where on the left side you'd have a menu and on the right side a content are where everything gets loaded when clicking a link in the menu. In the menu I'd have multiple stores where each store would have its own settings. Those settings would be initialized with an `id` to determine which content the view should display.

For the history mapper I guess one would have something like this:

```
/#LoginPlace:login
/#MainPlace:home
/#MainPlace:storeSettings?id=<id>
/#MainPlace:userSettings
etc..
```

---

In [2] it says

> "*In order to be accessible via a URL, an Activity needs a corresponding Place.*"

Which sounds to me like I should have a `LoginActivity` and a `MainActiviy` since after all `LoginActivity` is the first `Place` I arrive when I come to my website and `MainActivity` is the place I go when I am successfully logged in.

I'd have someting like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AbstractActivity implements LoginView.Presenter {
    // ..
    private void onLoginSuccess() {
        this.clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(new MainPlace());
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AbstractActivity implements MainView.Presenter {
    // ..
}
```

and of course have respective view `LoginView` and `MainView`.

This is how `AppActivityMapper.getActivity()` would look like:

```
@Override
public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
    if (place instanceof LoginPlace) {
        return new LoginActivity((LoginPlace) place, clientFactory);
    } else if (place instanceof MainPlace) {
        return new MainActivity((MainPlace) place, clientFactory);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So far so good but how would I implement the `MenuView` and the `MainContentView`?

I want to be able to click on menu items in the `MenuView` and update `MainContentView` and generate place tokens accordingly like:

```
/#MainPlace:home
/#MainPlace:storeSettings?id=<id>
/#MainPlace:userSettings
```

But I have no idea how to do that and how I would for example initialize my activity `StoreSettingsActivity` with the given `id`. I believe that I would need another `MainActivityMapper extends ActivityMapper` that now should control the place changes initiated by clicking on menu links but I just can't figure out how that could work.

I hope my question is clear, please let me know if you need some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think I once did something similar, it was not perfect because I had to deal with an existing architecture but it worked.

Here is what I did:

1. When a link from the menu is click execute `placeController.goTo(new MainPlace(id))`;
2. In your `ActivityMapper`, return your `MainActivity` in which you set the id of the `MainPlace`.
3. In your `MainActivity`, in the `start` method call a method that will initiate your `MainContentView` depending on the id of `MainPlace` you set earlier in the `MainActivity`.

I am pretty sure there is a better way of doing this, but it works and it can be a start that might help you to find a better solution.